# php - How do I print this multidimensional array?

Tags: php

Lets say I have the following array:

```
Array ( [1284487200] => Array ( [title] => first title [link] => http%3A%2F%2Fexample1.com ) [1261271380] => Array ( [title] => second title [link] => http%3A%2F%2Fexample2.com )
```

I want to print the array like this:

```
<a href="http://example1.com">first title - 1284487200</a><br>
<a href="http://example2.com">second title - 1261271380</a><br>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: the 2 answers provided have the same error in that my domain is included in the link, eg. http://www.mydomain.com/http%3A%2F%example1.com

Any way I can correct that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (most) difficult part is getting the key of the first dimension array, this is get using:

```
$key=>$data
```

in the foreach.

$key represents the key of the array being traversed. $data the content, in your example $data contains the second dimension array.

```
foreach( $array AS $key=>$data )
{
   echo '<a href="'.urldecode( $data['link'] ).'">'.$data['title'].' - '.$key.'</a><br>';
}
```

More info about the foreach statement: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $entry) {
    echo "<a href=\"{$entry['link']}\">{$entry['title']} - {$key}</a><br>";
}
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: neither of these answers is working correctly as it gives me my domain in the link eg. http://www.mydomain.com/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hush-hush.co.uk%2Fworld-sex-news%2FChina-Ramps-Up-Antiporn-Mission-by-Regulating-cn-Sites.php

Comment: it does for me, so any ideas why it might be happening?

Comment: @Steven Chances are your array is structured incorrectly. See it working here: http://ideone.com/jdb3R

Comment: Thanks, I think the error was caused by the encoded url, because the new code provided by clinisbut is working.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `foreach` loop, the `$key` will be the number, and the other information will be in `$value` as an array. I'm assuming you'll want to decode the link using `urldecode()` as well:

```
foreach($arr_name as $key => $value){
    $link = urldecode($value['link']);
    echo '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $key . ' - ' . $value['title'] . '</a><br>';
}
```

Comment: this code gives the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in ....

Comment: sorry that was a little sloppy -- left a bracket in there should work now